# Magento Widget's content in database

Tags: magento, widget

In Magento I have a static block (CMS>Static Block) that contains a widget. This widget contains WYSWIG field.

I write 'gks43o43l' into this field, paste the widget and save. The string shows in front end. When I search database for 'gks43o43l' nothing comes up. Where is this string stored?

Answer (score 2):

I can't find it because widget's content is base64 decoded. The encoded string is in 'cms_block' table.